# How early is Torah Or in Gemara?

Tags: history, jewish-books, talmud-gemara, tanach, publications

When was Torah Or compiled/available, and if different, when was it originally copied and/or printed with the Gemara text?

To clarify, this is not the chabad sefer Torah Or, but the references to Tanach that is quoted in Gemara that today appears beside it.

Comment: Apparently it was written in the 16th century, slightly after the start of the printing press but we'll before the Vilna Daf we have today. So the question is still where it was when it came out, and how it was incorporated into the daf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this enlightening discussion](http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10094), and [this Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%22%D7%A1_%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%94), the Torah Or was first printed with the version of the *gemara* printed between the years 1546-1551 by a Christian Venetian printer, Marco Antonio Yushtinian.

This version, in which Rabbi Yehoshua Boaz's additions were printed for the first time, was based on the second printed version of the [Bomberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Bomberg) version.

Interestingly, there's a plausible claim in the linked discussion that the Torah Or may not have been named by its author.

Comment: Great answer! Perhaps you could add when torah or was written exactly?

Comment: @andrewmh20 Unfortunately Rabbi Yehoshua Boaz himself doesn't mention Torah Or in his introduction to his written works (hence the claim that he wasn't the one who named it). His exact date of birth is a mystery as well (1472, 1500, 1518 are the suggestions in the Wikipedia article on him). The article says he wrote all his writings between ages 23-36, so it seems that it would be difficult to pinpoint when Torah Or specifically was written.